# Passing parameters to cmd.exec function

Tags: go

I want to read the text of multiple PDF files. I could not find proper Go lib, so I'm using [PDF2Text](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/cli/download) tool, and wrote the below code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    var files []string

    root := "."
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        if filepath.Ext(path) != ".pdf" {
            return nil
        }
        files = append(files, info.Name())
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file)
        cmd := exec.Command("pdf2text", "-o", "files", file)
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
        }
    }
}
```

This is working file, and extracting all pdf files into folder "files", but as demo version of this tool is extraction the pdf file into multiple text  file (file per page), I want to have the folder to which the PDF file is extracted to be same as the file name itself, so I tried replacing the:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("pdf2text", "-o", "files", file)
```

By

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("pdf2text", "-o", file, file)
```

But it did not work, nothing had been executed, no error had been thrown.

Comment: Can you first try if it works on the command line and then attempt it `exec.Command`?

Comment: @Inian it need a "string" in the cmd, I'm trying to pass the variable name in my code.

Comment: @Biffen did not understand your comment.

Comment: @HasanAYousef `file` _is_ a string.

Comment: @HasanAYousef How is `pdf2text` supposed to create a directory with the same name as the file?

Comment: This probably wouldn't even work  if done on the command line (at least not reliable). Don't  do such things. Write to a temporary dir an rename on success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments provided, the issue is because both output folder having the ext `.pdf` so the `pdf2txt` understand that I'm converting 2 pdf with the same name.

To fix it, I removed the ext `.pdf` from the first string which is to be used for the output directory name using `strings.Split` so my code became:

```golang
    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file)
        s := strings.Split(file, ".")
        cmd := exec.Command("pdf2text", "-o", s[0], file)
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
        }
    }
```